# Using attribute in class from friend and heritage c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

I think I really should explain myself about my question :p

So, I have a class c (let's start from the end), in this class c I want to use an attribute which is defined in class A. But my class c does not inherit from A, it is a friend of class b which inherit from A.

If i can, how cans i access this attribute ?

A little example in some kind of c++

```
class A
 protected:
   type THE_Attribute

class B: class A
 ...
 public:
   friend class c<type>;

class c:
  ....
  public:
   Need(THE_Attribute);
```

I hope you understood my question, thanks :)

Comment: Quick answer: You can't. Not unless you inherit class C from A then use getters to use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the member in class B:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }

    protected:
    int value = 0;
};

class B : private A
{
    friend class C;

    public:
    using A::print;

    private:
    int get_value() const { return A::value; }
    void set_value(int value) { A::value = value; }
};

class C
{
    public:
    void modify(B& b) { b.set_value(42); }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.print();
    C c;
    c.modify(b);
    b.print();
}
```